# Can I get iPhone or iPad Usage Stats from UIApplication?

Tags: iphone, ipad, statistics, uiapplication

Is it possible to access iPhone or iPad stats on App Usage through UIApplication or something.

Trying to figure out on some iPad's we have which apps are most viewed and overall how long they are used.

Comment: This would be ideal for building an app which reorganizes your home screen(s) based on the popularity of each app :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you do not have access to that information.